# Where is the mill?

Tags: bravely-default

I'm in Chapter 1, and I've just got the item that directs me to sneak into the Mill at midnight. But I can't find the mill anywhere in town or outside, even when it's dark out. So where is the mill?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have to do is to wait until night (just roam around on the world map) and then go to Ancheim. The mill entrance is on the same level as the palace.

Note that you can do this only after restoring the wind crystal.

Comment: Specifically the mill is the building that has a guard in front of it during the daytime.

Comment: Aha! My problem was that I hadn't yet restored the wind crystal.